# text in cells duplicating and not showing up until I scroll [Images]

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

So I'm loading a YouTube channel inside a tableView and trying to add the correct duration but sometimes it doesn't show up at all and when it does show up there's another text behind it if you look closely.

When you look at image 1 you can see that there's no time on one video until I scroll over it.

When you look at image 2 you can see that the text label is duplicated at some places

Code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
ChanelFeeds *currentFeed = [[xmlParser feeds] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


totalTime = [self timeFormatted:([currentFeed duration].intValue)-1];
    if([totalTime length] <= 4) {

        CGRect contentFrame6 = CGRectMake(0, 66, 30, 13);
        CGRect contentFrame7 = CGRectMake(6, 65, 60, 15);
        UILabel *title3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame7];
        UIImageView *imv5 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:contentFrame6];

        imv5.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"blackBorder.png"];
        imv5.alpha = 0.8;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imv5];

        title3.tag = 0013;
        title3.numberOfLines = 1;
        title3.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:title3];
        title3.text = totalTime;
        title3.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        title3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        imv5.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [imv5 release];
        [title3 release];
    } else if([totalTime length] == 5) {
        CGRect contentFrame6 = CGRectMake(87, 64, 30, 13);
        CGRect contentFrame7 = CGRectMake(90, 63, 60, 15);
        UILabel *title3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame7];
        UIImageView *imv5 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:contentFrame6];

        imv5.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"blackBorder.png"];
        imv5.alpha = 0.8;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imv5];

        title3.tag = 0013;
        title3.numberOfLines = 1;
        title3.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:title3];
        title3.text = totalTime;
        title3.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        title3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        imv5.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [imv5 release];
        [title3 release];
    }

}else{
    NSData* imageDataTemp = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[currentFeed thumbnailURL]];
    if(imageDataTemp){
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageDataTemp];
    }else{
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"youtubeLogo.png"];
    }


}

return cell;
```

}

[image: No duration at all]
[image: Text label on cell duplicating]

Answer (score 0):

May be change it like-

```
if (cell == nil)
{
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
```

Then, the block -

```
totalTime = [self timeFormatted:([currentFeed duration].intValue)-1];
    if([totalTime length] <= 4) {

        CGRect contentFrame6 = CGRectMake(0, 66, 30, 13);
        CGRect contentFrame7 = CGRectMake(6, 65, 60, 15);
        UILabel *title3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame7];
        UIImageView *imv5 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:contentFrame6];

        imv5.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"blackBorder.png"];
        imv5.alpha = 0.8;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imv5];

        title3.tag = 0013;
        title3.numberOfLines = 1;
        title3.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:title3];
        title3.text = totalTime;
        title3.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        title3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        imv5.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [imv5 release];
        [title3 release];
    } else if([totalTime length] == 5) {
        CGRect contentFrame6 = CGRectMake(87, 64, 30, 13);
        CGRect contentFrame7 = CGRectMake(90, 63, 60, 15);
        UILabel *title3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame7];
        UIImageView *imv5 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:contentFrame6];

        imv5.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"blackBorder.png"];
        imv5.alpha = 0.8;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imv5];

        title3.tag = 0013;
        title3.numberOfLines = 1;
        title3.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:title3];
        title3.text = totalTime;
        title3.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        title3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        imv5.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [imv5 release];
        [title3 release];
    }

}else{
    NSData* imageDataTemp = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[currentFeed thumbnailURL]];
    if(imageDataTemp){
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageDataTemp];
    }else{
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"youtubeLogo.png"];
    }


}
```

And then, - `return cell;`

The settings i.e. the second block shall be done **every time** a Cell is `dequed`, not only when a new is allocated.

Comment: Yeah but you're putting the image on top of the timer.

Comment: that u will know better :), my point is that the code shall be outside the `if(cell==nil){}`